# zsh PATH variable not properly set from another environment variable

Tags: zsh, environment-variables, path

I want to set my path (and some other environment variables) based on a certain directory, so I have the following file in my home directory

```
export MY_DIR="/path/to/dir"
export PATH=$MY_DIR/bin:$PATH
export MY_OTHER_VAR="$MY_DIR/folder"
```

I source that in my ~/.zshrc with the following line:
`[[ -e ~/my_file.sh ]] && emulate sh -c ' source ~/my_file.sh`

However, when I log in, `$MY_DIR/bin` is not in my path. If I `echo $PATH`, I get `%F{51}~%f` where `$MY_DIR/bin` should be. However, both MY_DIR and MY_OTHER_VAR were set correctly.

Have I done something wrong, or is this some weird bug in zsh (it seems to work as expected with bash)?

**Edit**

I have used both `source` and `~` elsewhere in my `zshrc` without issue. However, I tried moving the file to `/etc/zsh/my_file.sh` and sourcing it from `etc/zsh/zprofile`. I also tried using `.` rather than source, but even with those changes, I still see the same `%F{51}~%f` in my path variable. Actually, I've noticed that I see whatever my current directory is in the PATH variable, so for example, if I navigate to `/etc/zsh/` and `echo $PATH`, I see `%F{51}/etc/zsh%f`.

Full code to reproduce:

`/etc/zsh/zprofile`:

```
[[ -e /etc/zsh/my_file.sh ]] && emulate sh -c ' . /etc/zsh/my_file.sh'
```

`/etc/zsh/my_file.sh`:

```
export MY_DIR="/home/matt/code"
export PATH="$MY_DIR/bin:$PATH"
export MY_PYTHON="$MY_DIR/python"
```

**EDIT 2**

So I am using a custom prompt which prints my current path in cyan. If I disable that prompt, my PATH variable gets set properly. In the script for the prompt, I use a variable that I call `path` (lowercase). Apparently, while bash doesn't confuse it with `PATH`, zsh does. Thanks to all for the help.

Comment: Do you have the same effect with this same exact code example? I am asking because there is a syntax error in the example (the lone `"` on the end of the last line) and it looks like you changed the variable names and paths in order to "anonymize" the question. This could hide the actual issue, as it might have to do with the chosen variable names or the exact way how they are used. `%F{51}~%f` looks like it might be part of the prompt or some output (`print -P '%F{51}~%f'` will print a cyan colored `~`).

Comment: `sh` generally does not support `source` (but I'm not sure about `zsh` emulation of `sh`). In `sh`, you would use `.` (dot) instead.  Also, I'm likewise unsure how `zsh` treats the quoted tilde in this case. I would use `$HOME` instead.

Comment: There's undoubtedly an error in your code, but it doesn't seem to be in the part that you show, other than the missing quotes which wouldn't have this behavior. The missing quotes clearly show that you aren't showing us your actual code. Without seeing your code, we can't help you. Copy-paste [complete code that reproduces the problem](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) into your question.

Comment: sorry for the typo, I typed this question on mobile while on the go, which was probably a bad idea... Aside from the missing quotes, all I changed are the names of the paths and variables. Anyway, I've addressed all the comments in an edit

Comment: As @Adaephon suggested, the issue was related to my prompt (see my second edit). Thanks for the help.

Comment: `$path` is the array tied to `$PATH` in `zsh`, like in `csh` or `tcsh`.

Comment: @Kusalananda Ah yes, that would do it. In ZSH `path` is also used by the shell itself. It is an array, the content of which are (bi-directionally) synchronized with `PATH`. The array elements of `path` are identical to the colon-separated substrings of `PATH` and modifying either parameter will also change the other. Have a look at [this](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Set-By-The-Shell) and [this](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell) for a list of parameters used in some way by ZSH itself.

Comment: You have already 3 reopen votes, with 5 your question will be reopened. Welcome on the Unix SE!

Comment: @MattSpicer, you could write the solution as a proper answer, a short one to the point would do. Bonus points if you test what happens if you use `local path` instead in the function.

Comment: @ilkkachu zsh seg faults if I define a `local path` variable. I'm glad I had another terminal open when I sourced that :)

Comment: @MattSpicer, whoa. Well, apparently that's a bug [that's been reported](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2015/msg01305.html). Though in any case, it seems that even as `local`, `path` still acts like a (local) view into `PATH`, so probably not a good idea to use it anyway.

Comment: @ilkkachu Yeah, my solution was just to rename the variable instead. I actually wasn't familiar with the `local` keyword, though, so thanks for pointing that out to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My issue was actually not in the code where I was attempting to set the path to `"$MY_DIR/bin:$PATH"`, but in a different script that I was sourcing in my `.zshrc`. I'm using a custom script to set my shell prompt in which I used a variable declared as `path`, thinking that would not conflict with the environment variable `PATH`, but, as pointed out by @Adaephon in the comments, zsh [bidirectionally synchronizes](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/Doc/Release/Parameters.html#Parameters-Used-By-The-Shell) the `path` keyword with `PATH`.

Thus, for me, the solution was to rename the variable in my prompt function to `cur_path` (or similar). Attempting to define the variable as `local path` [will result in a segfault](https://www.zsh.org/mla/users/2015/msg01305.html).

Comment: You can define a local variable `$path` that does not behave like the special parameter `$path`, if you "hide" its specialness: `local -h path`. Alternative, you can define a local variable `$path` that _does_ behave like the special parameter `$fpath` if you invert the "hide" flag: `local +h path`.