# zsh script cannot find commmands

Tags: scripting, zsh, kali-linux, path

I'm attempting to run this zsh script:

```
#!/bin/zsh

paths=(
    "/docs/"
)

for path in $paths; do
    dirsearch.py -u "http://10.129.140.251:8080$path" \
        -r --csv-report="$(date +"%Y_%m_%d_%H_%M")_$path.csv"
    sleep(300)
done
```

When I attempt to run it I get these errors:

```
./dirsearch.sh:8: command not found: date
./dirsearch.sh:8: command not found: dirsearch.py
./dirsearch.sh:10: unknown file attribute: 3
```

Steps performed so far:

1. Verified that the folder which dirsearch.py is located in is added to path:

   ```
   export PATH=/home/user/targets/dirsearch:$PATH
   ```
2. Verified that I am using zsh as my current shell
3. Ran date and dirsearch.py commands without error from various locations on the pc.
4. Googled the issue.  Most solutions point to a path configuration error, but I don't see how mine is missconfigured.

Comment: See [zsh PATH variable not properly set from another environment variable](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/449692/zsh-path-variable-not-properly-set-from-another-environment-variable) and [What is the difference between $path and $PATH (lowercase versus uppercase) with zsh?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/532148/what-is-the-difference-between-path-and-path-lowercase-versus-uppercase-with) tl;dr - choose a different name for your `path` variable

Answer (score 2):

In Zsh, like in csh or tcsh before it, `$path` and `$PATH` are *tied* parameters that always reflect each other's values; updating one will also update the other. You can see this as follows:

```bash
% typeset path
typeset -aT PATH path=( /usr/bin /bin )
% typeset PATH path
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin
path=( /usr/bin /bin )
% path+=foo
% typeset PATH path
PATH=/usr/bin:/bin:foo
path=( /usr/bin /bin foo )
```

Because you override `$path` in your script, this will then also override `$PATH`.

The solution is to use a different variable name in your `for` loop (for example, `$_path` or `$dir`).